# Azure devops build pipeline: npm install task cannot find package folder when adding stages to pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, npm-install

I have written a build pipeline to build an ADF ARM template from a repository for later deployment.
For a first version I did not add any stages and defined the steps directly:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
subscriptionId: '########' 
resourceGroup: '#########'                      
dataFactory: '######'                       
PackageFolder: 'build'                                  
adfRootFolder: 'ADF'                                  

steps:

#Installs Node 
- task: NodeTool@0
inputs:
  versionSpec: '14.x'
displayName: 'Install Node.js'

#Installs the npm packages saved in your package.json file in the 
build
- task: Npm@1
inputs:
  command: 'install'    
  workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/$(adfRootFolder)/$(packageFolder)' 
  verbose: true
displayName: 'Install npm packages'
```

This works just fine.

However, now I want to extend the pipeline to contain different stages and therefore I addapted the code to the following:

```
trigger:
- none

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  subscriptionId: '#####'  
  resourceGroup: '######'                      
  dataFactory: '######'                       
  PackageFolder: 'build'                                  
  adfRootFolder: 'ADF'                                 

stages:

- stage: prd
  displayName: "Build adf"
  jobs:
    - deployment: 'build_adf'
      displayName: 'Build adf'
      continueOnError: false
      environment: 'env-dwh-prd'
      strategy:
        runOnce:
          deploy:
            steps:
            # Installs Node 
            - task: NodeTool@0
              inputs:
                versionSpec: '14.x'
              displayName: 'Install Node.js'

            # Installs the npm packages saved in your package.json file in the build
            - task: Npm@1
              inputs:
                command: 'install'
                workingDir: '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/$(adfRootFolder)/$(packageFolder)' 
                verbose: true
              displayName: 'Install npm packages'
```

And now all of a sudden, I get the following error:

> ##[error]Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/vsts/work/1/s/ADF/build'

I really do not know what's going on here. The definition of stages should not impact the pathes to the repository.

I tested the same structure of the pipeline and the repository with another build task where I did not use npm and in this pipeline I was able to access content of the folder provided in the same way
($(Build.Repository.LocalPath)/$(RootFolder)/$(packageFolder)') without any problem.
Maybe it has something to do with the way npm searches for folders...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deployment job doesn't download repository our of the box.

You need to add [checkout step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema/steps-checkout?view=azure-pipelines) to achieve this.

```
- checkout: self
```

Here you can find more about [deployment jobs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/deployment-jobs?view=azure-devops)

> Deployment jobs provide the following benefits:
>
> - Deployment history: You get the deployment history across pipelines, down to a specific resource and status of the deployments for auditing.
> - Apply deployment strategy: You define how your application is rolled out.
>
> A deployment job doesn't automatically clone the source repo. You can checkout the source repo within your job with checkout: self.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I completely missed that.

Comment: @SimonK could you upvote  my reply if it was helpful?

Comment: Yeah  of course. Sorry